# Soap authentication header and request using PHP

Tags: php, authentication, soap, soap-client

I am trying to setup a SOAP call for an online restaurant table booking service but haven't been able to get it working.
It uses authentication header and have tried the following code without any luck:

```
$username = '';
$password = '';

$soapURL = "http://m.cmd-it.dk/reservations.asmx?WSDL";

$client = new SoapClient($soapURL,array());

$auth = array(
    'UserName' => $username,
    'Password' => $password,
    'createReservation'=> array(
        'reservation2CompanyName' => 'Tester',
        'customerFirstName' => 'test',
        'customerLastName' => 'tester',
        'customerTelephoneNumber' => '22334455',
        'customerMail' => 'test@example.com',
        'reservationDate' => date("j/m/Y", time()),
        'reservationTime' => date("H:i", time()),
        'reservationPAX' => '3',
        'reservationRemarks' => 'test',
        'TestMode' => 1
    )
);
$header = new SoapHeader('http://cmd-it.dk/','authentification',$auth,false);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

echo var_dump($client->__getLastRequestHeaders());
echo var_dump($client->__getLastRequest());
```

But it just echo's NULL NULL... :-(

I am not familiar with PHP SOAP calls and not at all using authentication headers, but hope somebody can push me in the right direction.

Comment: Just pointing out that doing both `echo` and `var_dump` is redundant. `var_dump` doesn't return the input, but outputs it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you was near to reach your goal.  Here I have modified few lines of your code:

```
    <?php

    $username = '';
    $password = '';

    $soapURL = "http://m.cmd-it.dk/reservations.asmx?WSDL";

    $client = new SoapClient($soapURL,array());

    $auth = array(
        'UserName' => $username,
        'Password' => $password,
        'createReservation'=> array(
            'reservation2CompanyName' => 'Tester',
            'customerFirstName' => 'test',
            'customerLastName' => 'tester',
            'customerTelephoneNumber' => '22334455',
            'customerMail' => 'test@example.com',
            'reservationDate' => date("j/m/Y", time()),
            'reservationTime' => date("H:i", time()),
            'reservationPAX' => '3',
            'reservationRemarks' => 'test',
            'TestMode' => 1
        )
    );
    $header = new SoapHeader('http://cmd-it.dk/','authentification',$auth,false);
    $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

    /* Requesting function list (interface) from SOAP server */
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($client->__getFunctions());

    /* Executing a fuction, for example isAlive method */
    $response = $client->__soapCall("isAlive", array("isAlive" => "true"));
    var_dump($response);



/* Here a list of functions available on your server that we have requested by getFucntions() method */
/*
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(44) "isAliveResponse isAlive(isAlive $parameters)"
  [1]=>
  string(74) "createReservationResponse createReservation(createReservation $parameters)"
  [2]=>
  string(44) "isAliveResponse isAlive(isAlive $parameters)"
  [3]=>
  string(74) "createReservationResponse createReservation(createReservation $parameters)"
}
*/
```

In the above example we will ask for interface (getfunctions) and execute a SOAP method (__soapCall).

Regards

Comment: Thanks a lot, works very well calling isAlive, but how do I go about creating the reservation and get the proper response from the server?
Have tried a few combinations, but can't seem to get it to work.
Thought that $client->__soapCall("createReservation", $auth); would work. :-/

Answer (score 2):

There are two things that you need. As per the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php) of `__getLastRequestHeaders()` and `__getLastRequest()`:

> This function only works if the SoapClient object was created with the
>   trace option set to TRUE.

So, you need this:

```
$client = new SoapClient($soapURL,array(
        'trace' => 1
));
```

Also, the documentation mentions the following:

> Returns the SOAP headers from the last request.
>
> Returns the XML sent in the last SOAP request.

So, before calling `__getLastRequestHeaders()` and `__getLastRequest()`, you have to make a request. You can check the available functions with:

```
var_dump($client->__getFunctions());
```

and see that there is function `isAlive()`. So, inserting:

```
var_dump($client->isAlive());
```

before `__getLastRequestHeaders()` and `__getLastRequest()` will give you results.