# How to map a curl request in PHP to consume a soap service

Tags: php, curl, soap, php-curl

**EDIT**:
I need a way to consume a SOAP service using PHP.

```
curl -vvvv -k -s -X POST --header 'Content-type: text/xml;charset="utf-8"' --header 'SOAPAction: vend' -u 'USER':'PIN' -d "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soapenv:Header/><soapenv:Body><vend xmlns=\"http://host.vim.services.co.uk/xsd\"><sequence>6922343</sequence><origMsisdn>xxxxxxxxxxxxx </origMsisdn><destMsisdn>xxxxxxxxxxxxx</destMsisdn><amount>1000</amount><tariffTypeId>1</tariffTypeId></vend></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>" https://xxx.xxx.x.xxx:443/modlue/services/TargetOne ; echo;
```

Already, I have this piece of curl request (above), which gives me a successful response as shown below.

```
* Trying xxx.xxx.x.xxx...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to xxx.xxx.x.xxx (xxx.xxx.x.xxx) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.xxx.xxxxxxe.com
*  start date: Sep 10 00:00:00 2018 GMT
*  expire date: Nov 28 12:00:00 2020 GMT
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; OU=www.digicert.com; CN=RapidSSL RSA CA 2018
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Server auth using Basic with user 'username'
> POST /axis2/services/HostIFService HTTP/1.1
> Host: xxx.xxx.x.xxx
> Authorization: Basic V4mp00vKL2wb3LL6Z2hZZSIzI2RzCL2kbNPlQjExMQ==
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-type: text/xml;charset="utf-8"
> SOAPAction: vend
> Content-Length: 409
>
* upload completely sent off: 409 out of 409 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200
< Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 568
< Date: Wed, 15 Jan 2020 14:24:53 GMT
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
<
* Connection #0 to host xxx.xxx.x.xxx left intact
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><xsd:vendResponse xmlns:xsd="http://xxxxxx.xxx.xxxxx.xx.xx/xxx"><xsd:sequence>0000000001</xsd:sequence><xsd:statusId>301</xsd:statusId><xsd:txRefId>2020011515245375604706230</xsd:txRefId><xsd:origBalance>0.00</xsd:origBalance><xsd:origMsisdn>12345678910112 </xsd:origMsisdn><xsd:destMsisdn>12345678910112</xsd:destMsisdn><xsd:responseCode>0</xsd:responseCode><xsd:responseMessage>Insufficient Airtime</xsd:responseMessage></xsd:vendResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

However, I want to be able to transform the curl request into a proper PHP class (using either SoapClient or any other library) so that I can be able to extract the response for use in my application.

**QUESTION**
How can I achieve this using PHP?

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED**
I have tried the code below from NuSoap library and have also tried to follow the answer from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30225281/soap-authentication-header-and-request-using-php) but keep getting this `Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from ...`.
SoapClient is enabled in my apache server.

```
$params = array(
  "param" => "value"
);

$soap_client = new nusoap_client($wsdl_url, true);
$soap_client->setCredentials(USER_SERVICE, PASS_SERVICE, 'basic');
$soap_client->soap_defencoding = 'UTF-8'; //Fix encode erro, if you need
$soap_return = $soap_client->call("method_name", $params);
```

**MORE INFORMATION**
Below is a sample WSDL request and corresponding response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?> 
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:xsd="http://host.vim.services.co.uk/xsd"> 
<soapenv:Header/> 
<soapenv:Body> 
<xsd:vend> 
<xsd:origMsisdn>2349062058470</xsd:origMsisdn> 
<xsd:destMsisdn>09062058617</xsd:destMsisdn> 
<xsd:amount>100</xsd:amount> 
<xsd:sequence>138</xsd:sequence> 
<xsd:tariffTypeId>1</xsd:tariffTypeId> 
<xsd:serviceproviderId>1</xsd:serviceproviderId> 
</xsd:vend> 
</soapenv:Body> 
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

NB: The request should contain a header field of the form Authorization: Basic , where credentials are the base64 encoding of id and password joined by a colon.
Below are the applicable client context object properties.

```
Authorization Data : MjM0OTAwMDAwMTIzNC9oYW5kc2V0OjU1MjY= 
charset : UTF-8
content-type : application/xml
SoapAction : urn:Vend
```

And finally, here is the response to the request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?> 
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> 
<soapenv:Header/> 
<soapenv:Body> 
<vendResponse> 
<destBalance>998860.0</destBalance> 
<destMsisdn>09062058617</destMsisdn> 
<origBalance>999360.0</origBalance> 
<origMsisdn>2349062058470</origMsisdn> 
<responseCode>0</responseCode> 
<responseMessage>Successful</responseMessage> 
<sequence>139</sequence> 
<statusId>0</statusId> 
<txRefId>2018122611455497901000006</txRefId> 
<voucherPIN>40692125281574</voucherPIN> 
<voucherSerial>600000000001</voucherSerial> 
</vendResponse> 
</soapenv:Body>
```

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "parse", and what is not working with the given code?

Comment: What i mean by parse is using php soap client instead of the curl

Comment: And what's the problem with the given code?

Comment: it gives Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from

Comment: Please add all error messages to the question by editing it, along with your debugging attempts

Comment: It 's 2020 and people still use the NuSoap library? All you need is the WSDL uri and the cert file for the TLS handshake. Based on the WSDL you can read out the definitions for request and response types for all functions the webservice provides. With this informations you can translate complex types into php classes. Build classmap and init the PHP SoapClient class with the right options and call the vend function with its parameters. Easy as pie. First: what is the WSDL URL?

Comment: Hello Marcel, I have edited the question. You can take a look and give me good suggestions.